# Product of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Say that I have a process that produces these values $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$  as follows:

1. We have a constant $c$.
2. We have a random number generator that gives us $\epsilon$ following a bell distribution with a zero mean ($\mu = 0$) and  some standard deviation ($\sigma$).
3. For any $i$, $X_i = c + \epsilon$.

I guess the above would imply that the mean of $X_1, ..., X_n$ is asymptotically going to converge at $c$.  Is this right?

My quesetieon is about their products. What about their products?  E.g. $X_1 X_2 \ldots X_n$.  Anything that can be said?  E.g.

1. Can we say that $X_1X_2\ldots X_n = Z^n$?
2. Perhaps with some bounds?  E.g. sandwitch the answer?

My goal is to solve the product $X_1X_2 \ldots X_n$ more simply.

Comment: You can describe the $X_i$ more simply as normal random variables with mean $c$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Are they independent? I suspect searching on "products of normal random variables" will yield information.

Comment: First try to look at $n^{-1}\log |\prod_{i=1}^n X_i| $ and see where it leads.